# AttributeError: 'hyperopt_estimator' object has no attribute '_best_preprocs'

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, scikit-learn, hyperopt

I'm trying to optimize the performance of a `sklearn.svm.LinearSVC` using [hyperopt-sklearn](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt-sklearn). I'm using the `LinearSVC` to predict image labels of the CIFAR-10 dataset, and am hoping through *hyperopt* I'll get improved performance.

However, despite multiple runs, when I run the following:

```
model = HyperoptEstimator(classifier=hpc.svc_linear('mySVC'),
                           max_evals=10,trial_timeout=10)
model.fit(x,y)
```

I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'hyperopt_estimator' object has no attribute '_best_preprocs'`

This is a bug, as noted in [this open issue on the hyperopt-sklearn GitHub](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt-sklearn/issues/67), but has no solution. Anyone been able to bypass this error?